# How do you use Stacks to make a Decimal to Binary to Octa to HexaDecimal Conversion?

Tags: java, stack

Here is the code I've already made:

```
import java.util.Stack;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conversion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
    int numb =sc.nextInt();

    while(numb!=0){
        int bin = numb%2;
        s.push(bin);
        numb /=2;
    }
    System.out.println("Binary:");
    while(!(s.isEmpty())){
        System.out.print(s.pop());
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

}
```

My problem is already in my Question and as you can see here is that I've already made the binary conversion and I don't know to start

Comment: `System.out.printf("Binary: %s%n", Integer.toBinaryString(numb));`

Comment: then how do I also implement the other 2 which is octa and hexadecimal with using only stacks

Comment: Why? [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) also has `toOctalString(int)` and `toHexString(int)`.

Comment: you demonstrated how to do binary (divide by 2) push on stack.  do the appropriate algorithm for the other bases. do you have an algorithm in English or pseudo code that you do not know how to turn into code?

Comment: Do you really mean exactly what you said in your title? That is, convert form decimal to binary and thence from binary to octal and thence from octal to hexadecimal? And if so, why?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can I apply it using stacks?

Comment: @KoryGill soo basically all I have an idea on how to because you just divide it to what you want it to be converted to like for example decimal to octal you just divide it by 8 but I don't know how to apply it and most definitely when the condition is using only `Stacks`

Comment: @EJP yes, well that was the condition given to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack needs to be cloned before it is popped, since the stack becomes empty once it is popped.

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
        int numb = sc.nextInt();

        while (numb != 0) {
            int bin = numb % 2;
            s.push(bin);
            numb /= 2;
        }

        Stack<Integer> st = (Stack<Integer>) s.clone(); // Added this line

        System.out.println("Binary:");
        while (!(s.isEmpty())) {
            System.out.print(s.pop());
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Octal: "
                + changeBase((Stack<Integer>) st.clone(), 8)); // Added this line
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal: "
                + changeBase((Stack<Integer>) st.clone(), 16)); // Added this line
    }

    public static String changeBase(Stack<Integer> st, int base) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int length = st.size();

        int bitsPerDecimal = 0, base_copy = base;
        while (base_copy > 1) {
            base_copy /= 2;
            ++bitsPerDecimal;
        }

        int padding = bitsPerDecimal - (length % bitsPerDecimal); // make size of stack multiple  of bitsPerDecimal
        for (int i = 0; i < padding; ++i) {
            st.push(0);
        }

        while (!st.empty()) {
            int no = 0, pow = base;
            for (int i = 0; i < bitsPerDecimal; ++i) { // Get the required bits to make a digit
                pow /= 2;
                no = no + pow * st.pop();
            }
            if (no > 9)
                result.append((char) ('A' + (no - 10)));
            else
                result.append(Integer.toString(no));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```